# User Input in Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script now that creates a big matrix based on all kinds of variables.

A few variables change periodically and their values are hard-coded so I need to update the script often.

How can I prompt a dialog and ask the user for some info and then use said info for a few of my variables? I just want a dialog with a couple text boxes for user input and an OK button to continue the script.

Answer (score 3):

Found it. You simply create your variable like this:

```
var buildVersion = Browser.inputBox("Build Version");
```

This will create a popup dialog that asks the user to input the "Build Version"

Comment: This is only effective in scripts that are container-bound in Google Spreadsheets. (Only Spreadsheets have a Browser object.)

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad. You're right. I specified Spreadsheets in the title and in the tags, but not the question or answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

In Google Sheets:

The following will pop up a dialog box prompting the user for input that can be assigned to a variable:

```
var YourVariableNameHere = browser.inputbox("Your Question Here");
```

It Creates a input-request-box that looks accordingly:

[Inputbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ustQU.png)

I have gone on to successfully use the variable to rename sheets, enter the variable into respective cells etc.